# Django queries merged with "|" return duplicates

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a `Channel` model.

In my views, I have the following lines :

```
def default_channels(request) :     return Channel.objects.filter(is_default=True)
def subbed_channels(request):       return Channel.objects.filter(subscribers=request.user)
def moderated_channels(request):    return Channel.objects.filter(moderators=request.user)
```

and then

```
channels = default_channels(request) | subbed_channels(request) | moderated_channels(request)
```

Normally, if I understand things correctly, this should return all the channels that are default, that I have subscribed to, or that I moderate. However, if a channel is present in several of those filters, it should not be returned more than once.

However, for some reason, the `channels` object returns some of the objects several times. I even have a channel that is returned 4 times !

How can I debug and solve this ? Am I using the "|" operator wrongly ?

Comment: queryset has a .distinct() method which you can use to remove duplicate queries: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values  However, look into model manager. Also, all those views can possibly be combined into one.

Comment: Thanks @user2707389, `distinct()` seems to be the most logical fix. I have several other views that combine different variants of my channels, which is why I built it like this. Do you want to post your `distinct()` solution so that I can mark it as best ?

Comment: posted my solution. feel free to mark that as correct. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

queryset has a `.distinct()` method which you can use to remove duplicate queries.

Read the documentation [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values).

However, look into model manager. All those views can possibly be combined into one.

Answer (score 1):

```
channels = default_channels(request) | subbed_channels(request) | moderated_channels(request)

channels = channels.distinct()
```

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish what you want is better using [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/). In your case:

```
from django.db.models import Q

channels = Channel.objects.filter(Q(is_default=True) | Q(subscribers=request.user) | Q(moderators=request.user))
```

should do the work.

Comment: Hello @Sirion, and thanks for your reply. Why is it better to use Q ?

Comment: Q objects are made exactly for this use case and are best documented then using `|` (which is a django internal feature and therefore not reliable, I think). Moreover my approach will generate just 1 query which is better then 3 queries (even if I'm not completely sure there will be actually 3 queries using your approach or just one).

Comment: I had some problem using your suggested approach, this was my code `Organization.objects.filter(Q(userRoles__role__lte=at_least_level) | Q(created_by=user))`. The first Q produced 0 results, the second one. With your approach the queryset has 2 elements (the latter repeated twice), I still had to call `.distinct()`.

Comment: Using `Q(conditionA) | Q(conditionB)` should select only records that match conditionA or conditionB. In any case, the number of selected records should never be bigger than the sum of the number of records found with `filter(conditionA)` plus the number of records found with `filter(conditionB)`, which seems to be your case. Maybe the join used in your first condition is a case that is not handled properly. Have a look at the SQL query that is generated and check if it actually does what you need.